# Probabilistic combinatorial optimization problem on the distances between pairs of points in $[0,1]$

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, probability-distributions, combinatorial-optimization

Let $S$ be a set of $n \gg 1$ points lying on the interval $[0,1]$. Given a point $p\in[0,1]$, let $S_p\subseteq S\times S$ be the set formed by all pairs of points $(x,y)$ with $x,y\in S$, such that either $\max(x,y)\le p$ or $\min(x,y)\ge p$. Finally let $d(S_p)=\frac{1}{|S_p|}\sum_{(x,y)\in S_p} |x-y|$ be the average distance between any two points in $S_p$.

---

**Question:** If $p$ is selected uniformly at random in $[0,1]$, what is the maximum expected value
$m(n)$ of $d(S_p)$ over all possible sets $S$ of $n$ points in $[0,1]$ (i.e., $m(n):=\max_{S\in[0,1]^n}\mathbb{E}_p\left[d(S_p)\right]$)?

---

---

*Can we at least find a good lower bound for $m(n)$, when $n\to\infty$?*

*Can we calculate the value of $m(n)$ if $p$ is equal to $\tfrac14$, $\tfrac12$ and $\tfrac34$, all with probability $\tfrac13$ (instead of being selected uniformly at random in $[0,1]$)? (I guess it's a simpler question and can provide insights about the main problem above.)*

Comment: Did you allow $(x, x)$ to be included in $S_p$ on purpose? Those pairs increase the size of $S_p$ without contributing to the sum of distances.

Comment: You can have $(x,y)\in S_p$ such that $x=y$. There are no additional constraints. For instance, If $p=\alpha$ with probability $1$, where $\alpha\in[0,1]$ (i.e., instead of being selected uniformly at random in [0,1] as written in the problem text, $p$ is fixed in $[0,1]$), the problem becomes *deterministic* and is trivial: one easily obtains $m(n)$ approaching $\max(p,1-p)/2=\max(\alpha,1-\alpha)/2$ as $n$ increases (half of the points placed in $p=\alpha$ and the other half placed in the farthest endpoint from $p=\alpha$ of the interval $[0,1]$).

Comment: Thank you @araomis for your answer (previously) below. Why did you delete it? I did not have enough time these days to analyze it, and I would be glad to read it this weekend.

Comment: I added it again, sorry. I was not so sure anymore whether it really contributes anything interesting. Let me know ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that gives a lower bound, that I expect to be tight.
The first step is to observe that if $\mu$ is a non-atomic
probability distribution  on $[0,1]$,
$(X_i)_{i=1}^n$ are iid and $\mu$ distributed, and $L_n=n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i}$ the associated empirical measure, then
$$ m_n\geq E_\mu\times E_p \big( \frac{\int\int L_n(dx) L_n(dy) (1-1_{x< p< y})|x-y|}{\int \int L_n(dx) L_n(dy) (1-1_{x<p<y})}\big).$$
Now, $$\int\int L_n(dx) L_n(dy) (1-1_{x< p< y})|x-y|\to_{n\to\infty}\int\int \mu(dx)\mu(dy)|x-y|(1-1_{x<p<y})$$
and
$$\int\int L_n(dx) L_n(dy) (1-1_{x< p< y})\to_{n\to\infty}\int\int \mu(dx)\mu(dy)(1-1_{x<p<y})$$
So altogether,
asymptotically,
$$ \liminf_{n\to\infty}m_n \geq \sup_{\mu}\int_0^1 dp \frac {\int\int \mu(dx)\mu(dy)|x-y|(1-1_{x<p<y})}{\int\int \mu(dx)\mu(dy)(1-1_{x<p<y})}.$$
For example, a straight forward bound can be obtained by choosing $\mu$ itself to be Lebesgue on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ofer. I am sorry, I think that I am missing why you wrote $x<p<y$ whereas I am interested in the case we have either $\max(x,y)\le p$ or $\min(x,y)\ge p$.

Comment: @Penelope Benenati You are right, I misread. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks @ofer. Why do you say that you "expect [your approach] to be tight"?

Comment: By tight I mean that I expect it to give the correct asymptotics for the maximum (in spite of the fact that it is only a lower bound, which is what you asked about).  The reasoning (which I have not tried to transform into a formal proof) goes as follows: suppose you have a near optimal $S=S_n$ (that nearly achieves the maximum). Consider the empirical measure. It has a converging subsequence (as $n\to\infty$) to some measure $\mu$. Now apply the argument I wrote with that $\mu$.

Comment: The only places where you need care (in writing a formal proof) is that $1_{x<p<y}$ is not a continuous function of $(x,y)$. But  you can get around that by mollification, since $p$ has a smooth law.

Comment: Thank you, interesting. By "tight", in my last question here, I meant the same. Could you please provide more information about how to quantify how far from the optimum one can go by mollification?

Comment: Asymptotically, 0 distance. Replace $1_{x<p<y}$ by $g_\epsilon(p,x,y)$ continuous, so that $g_\epsilon(p,x,y)=1$ if $x<p-\epsilon$ and $y>p+\epsilon$ and $g_\epsilon(p,x,y)=0$ if $x> p-\epsilon/2$ and $y>x+\epsilon/2$. Now you get a bound (that depends at $\epsilon$) and then at the end take $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you once again @ofer. I also would need an upper bound, asking help for a rigorous proof showing that $m(n)$ is smaller than a certain constant I can obtain via numerical simulations, when $n$ is large enough (still finite). Do you suggest me to create another similar post for the upper bound? I hope this does not go against the rules of the community.

Comment: What I wrote is that the formula I gave should also be an (asymptotic) upper bound, that is, I believe that $\lim_{n\to\infty} m_n$. equals the formula I wrote. If you want a finite $n$ result then yes, by all means, start another question. I have no idea how to compute a finite $n$ upper bound.

Comment: Of course, but the case $n$ finite is important in the underlying research work I am doing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to answer any of your questions yet. However, I have derived a close form solution for the expectation $\mathbb{E}_p(d(S_p))$, given a set $S$. If my derivation is correct, it seems to me that we might be able to compute $\max_{S \in [0, 1]} \mathbb{E}_p(d(S_p))$ using mathematical optimization techniques on the closed form solution.

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a finite set of $n$ points and consider $S^2 = \binom{S}{2}$. We first study $d(S^2) = \frac{1}{\lvert S^2 \rvert}\sum_{(x, y) \in S^2} \lvert x - y \rvert$. To this end, consider the points of $S$ sorted from least to largest: $s_1, \dots, s_n$. For arbitrary $i \in [n-1]$ we observe that there are exactly $i(n - i)$ pairs $(x, y) \in S^2$ such that the line segment $\overline{s_i s_{i + 1}}$ is contained in the line segment $\overline{xy}$. We get: $$d(S^2) = \frac{1}{\lvert S^2 \rvert}\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}i(n - i)(s_{i + 1} - s_i)$$

Next, let $p \in [0, 1]$ such that $p \notin S$. Consider the set $S_p$ as you defined it. The point $p$ splits the points in $S$ into two parts: Those larger than $p$ and those smaller than $p$. Assume that exactly $i$ points are smaller than $p$. The set $S_p$ consists of two disjoint subsets $S_{>p}$ and $S_{<p}$: The set $S_{>p}$ contains all pairs $(x, y)$ with $\min(x, y) \geq p$ while $S_{<p}$ is the set of all pairs $(x, y)$ with $\max(x, y) \leq p$. Thus $S_p$ contains exactly $\binom{i}{2} + \binom{n - i}{2}$ pairs. Moreover, we can use the formula from above on $S_{>p}$ and $S_{<p}$:
$$d(S_p) = \frac{1}{\lvert S_p \rvert}\left(\sum_{(x, y) \in S_{<p}} \lvert x - y \rvert + \sum_{(x, y) \in S_{>p}} \lvert x - y \rvert\right) \\ 
= \frac{1}{\lvert S_p \rvert}\left( \lvert S_{>p} \rvert d(S_{>p}) + \lvert S_{<p} \rvert d(S_{<p}) \right)\\
= \frac{1}{\lvert S_p \rvert}\left( \sum_{j = 1}^{i - 1}j(i - j)(s_{j + 1} - s_j) + \sum_{j = i}^{n - 1}(j - i + 1)(n - (j + 1))(s_{j + 1} - s_j)\right)$$

Hence we have a closed form formula for $d(S_p)$ for some particular $S$ and $p \notin S$. As a next step we notice that the probability that exactly $i$ points of $S$ are smaller than $p$ is equal to the probability of $p$ lying on the segment $\overline{s_i s_{i + 1}}$ which of course is equal to the length of the segment $\overline{s_i s_{i + 1}}$. Hence we have derived a closed form for the expectation $\mathbb{E}_p(d(S_p))$ for given $S$. For simplicity, define $s_0 = 0$ and $s_{n + 1} = 1$:

$$\mathbb{E}_p(d(S_p)) = \sum_{i = 0}^n Pr(p \in \overline{s_i s_{i + 1}}) d(S_p) \\
= \sum_{i = 0}^n (s_{i + 1} - s_i) \frac{1}{\binom{i}{2} + \binom{n - i}{2}}\left( \sum_{j = 1}^{i - 1}j(i - j)(s_{j + 1} - s_j) + \sum_{j = i}^{n - 1}(j - i + 1)(n - (j + 1))(s_{j + 1} - s_j)\right) 
$$

EDIT: If the points are spread equidistantly the formula simplifies to:
$$\sum_{i = 0}^n (s_{i + 1} - s_i) \frac{1}{\binom{i}{2} + \binom{n - i}{2}}\left( \sum_{j = 1}^{i - 1}j(i - j)(s_{j + 1} - s_j) + \sum_{j = i}^{n - 1}(j - i + 1)(n - (j + 1))(s_{j + 1} - s_j)\right) \\
= \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{\binom{i}{2} + \binom{n - i}{2}} \left( \sum_{j = 1}^{i - 1}j(i - j) + \sum_{j = i}^{n - 1}(j - i + 1)(n - (j + 1)) \right) \\
= \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{\binom{i}{2} + \binom{n - i}{2}} \left( \sum_{j = 1}^{i - 1}j(i - j) + \sum_{j = 1}^{n - i}j(n - i + 1 - j) \right)
$$

There is a formula for the two inner sums: $\sum_{j = 1}^{i - 1}j(i - j) = i\sum_{j = 1}^{i - 1}j - \sum_{j = 1}^{i - 1}j^2 = i\frac{i(i - 1)}{2} + \frac{(i - 1)i(2(i - 1) + 1)}{6} = \frac{3i^2(i - 1) + 2(i - 1)^2i + i(i - 1)}{6} = \frac{3i^3 - 3i^2 + 2i^3 - 4i^2 + 2i + i^2 - i}{6} = \frac{5i^3 - 6i^2+ i}{6}$

Plugging this in yields:
$$\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{\binom{i}{2} + \binom{n - i}{2}} \left( \frac{5i^3 - 6i^2+ i}{6} + \frac{5(n - i + 1)^3 - 6(n - i + 1)^2+ (n - i + 1)}{6} \right) \\
= \frac{1}{6(n-1)^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{5i^3 - 6i^2+ i + 5(n - i + 1)^3 - 6(n - i + 1)^2+ (n - i + 1)}{\binom{i}{2} + \binom{n - i}{2}}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The approach is clear and looks correct (perhaps there is a typo when you wrote "Thus $S_p$ contains exactly $i^2 + (n - i)^2$ pairs" if I am not wrong, anyway nothing really important). The difficult part is maximizing the last expression over all $s_i$ for $1\le i\le n$. Numerical simulations suggests that we obtain $0.40$ for $n=4$, $0.31$ for $n=8$, less than $0.29$ for $n=16$. Furthermore, the distance between two consecutive points seems to be equal up to $1/(n-1)$ up to a (small) constant factor, and we always have $s_1=0$ and $s_n=1$.

Comment: I feel confident that $m(n)$ is monotonically decreasing in $n$. @araomis, do you have any idea related to your expression about how to prove this property?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have added an edit for the case where the points are distributed equidistantly, but I didn't get so far yet. I'll let you know if I get anywhere (also wrt your conjecture about monotonicity). Considering the line "Thus $S_p$ contains $i^2 + (n - i)^2$ pairs": My idea was that the size of $S_{<p}$ is $i^2$ and the size of  $S_{>p}$ is $(n - i)^2$. Together they make up $S_p$. Let me know if you still think there is a mistake, I don't see it yet.

Comment: Thank you for your edit and your comment! About the expression $i^2+(n-i)^2$, you defined $i$ as the the number of points smaller than $p$. You wrote that the set $S_{<p}$ contains all pairs of points smaller than $p$, and its cardinality is equal to $i^2$. If $i=1$, the number such pairs is $0$. If $i=2$ the number of such pairs is $1$. Hence, I am understanding now that (1) when you talk about *pairs*, you mean *ordered pairs*, while I was meaning *unordered pairs*.

Comment: Hence there is a factor $2$ between the number of pairs we were analyzing, which should not be a big deal anyway (I think it's my fault because I used the notation $(x,y)$ instead of $\{x,y\}$).(2) You also think that the *same* point $x$ *alone* can form a pair by being used twice, i.e. $(x,x)$. However I was talking about each pair as formed by two *distinct* points $x,y\in S$, which can possibly be *coincident* (for instance we can have $x=0.3$, $y=0.3$ and $(x,y)$ is a pair of points taken from $S$ -- "without replacement"). Just some little misunderstanding,I should have been clearer.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Yes, I misunderstood you, I'll change it.